# Specialized Text Console in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, console, wxpython

Is there any way that I can build an interactive text console using wxPython window application? It will be used to allow user to provide natural language input for the application to parse the grammar based on the language selected. It is not going to be used to run any shell or commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wx.TextCtrl for input and then when the user is done typing, you can have them press a button to do whatever checking you want done. Alternatively, you could use a wx.Timer to watch for idleness so when the user is idle for x seconds, it does the checking you want automatically too.